# PHP file_exists returns false when variable is in file name

Tags: php, filenames, file-exists

I want to check if a `jpeg` file exists on my server. However, when I check it, the return value is false.

```
clearstatcache();

// the $img variable is dynamically got from $split[1] which is something like image.jpeg" />
$img = str_replace('"','',$split[1]); // remove double quotes
$img = str_replace('/>','',$img); // remove img end tag
$img = str_replace(' ','',$img); // remove spaces

$filename = "uploads/image.jpeg"; // original file name
$fn = "uploads/".$img; // file name with dynamic variable in it
if(file_exists($fn)){
       echo "yes";
}else{
       echo "no";
}

// Check if the two strings are the same and they are
if($fn == $filename){
       echo "same";
}
```

The original static file name returns back `yes`, while the dynamic one gives back `no`. I checked and `safe_mode` is `off` on my server and the two variables (`$fn` and `$filename`) are completely the same. If I just simply make `$img` equal to `image.jpeg` without any `str_replace` it also gives back `true` and echos out `yes`.
Overall, I do not know what is the problem with the `$img` variable and why does it give me back two different results, if the variables are the same?

Comment: `var_dump($filename, $fn)` please…

Comment: Also, `/uploads/...` refers to the directory `uploads` **in the root directory of your harddisk**. Is that correct? Somehow I doubt it is.

Comment: `var_dump` gives me back `string(97) "permUploads/_jrP_Nq_X3hHsXdQ0_vHG1Yr5Z_touryx_xZsxsYCiAzWNNj9hc8HIck_UN9BISgxszzNvmV_uOq.jpeg
" string(93) "permUploads/_jrP_Nq_X3hHsXdQ0_vHG1Yr5Z_touryx_xZsxsYCiAzWNNj9hc8HIck_UN9BISgxszzNvmV_uOq.jpeg"`. Two strings that are the same, but with different length. How Is that?

Comment: @MarkFrankli 93 != 97 There's your problem

Comment: The first string clearly has some trailing whitespace…

Comment: I see, but how could I make the two strings with the same length?

Comment: This makes no sense, `if($fn == $filename){` should have failed. I am going to assume you have confused some outputs here

Comment: But actually I removed that before.

Comment: Remove the trailing whitespace, e.g. `trim()`. But really, I'd question how you extract the string from what is probably HTML in the first place.

Comment: Any luck yet, have you tried my debugging suggestion?

Comment: One more reason not to parse HTML with string slicing or regular expressions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some serious flaw in your debugging logic somewhere, try this:

```
echo '<hr/>';

clearstatcache();

// the $img variable is dynamically got from $split[1] which is something like image.jpeg" />
$img = str_replace('"','',$split[1]); // remove double quotes
$img = str_replace('/>','',$img); // remove img end tag
$img = str_replace(' ','',$img); // remove spaces

$filename = "uploads/image.jpeg"; // original file name
$fn = "uploads/".$img; // file name with dynamic variable in it
if(file_exists($fn)){
    echo '$fn: yes';
    echo '<br/>';
}else{
    echo '$fn: no';
    echo '<br/>';
}

if(file_exists($filename)){
    echo '$filename: yes';
    echo '<br/>';
}else{
    echo '$filename: no';
    echo '<br/>';
}

// Check if the two strings are the same and they are
if($fn == $filename){
    echo "same";
    echo '<br/>';
}
else
{
    echo 'different';
    echo '<br/>';
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $split[1], $filename, $fn )
echo '</pre>';

echo '<hr/>';
```

Comment: Actually, the same as it was. `$fn: no
$filename: no
different
string(93) "permUploads/_jrP_Nq_X3hHsXdQ0_vHG1Yr5Z_touryx_xZsxsYCiAzWNNj9hc8HIck_UN9BISgxszzNvmV_uOq.jpeg"
string(97) "permUploads/_jrP_Nq_X3hHsXdQ0_vHG1Yr5Z_touryx_xZsxsYCiAzWNNj9hc8HIck_UN9BISgxszzNvmV_uOq.jpeg
"`. I simply cannot remove spaces neither with `trim()` nor with `str_replace`.

Comment: @MarkFrankli Your web browser is hiding characters from your eyes. Instead of copy+pasting from your web browsers normal display you need to look at the source code; `ctrl` + `u` in Chrome.

Comment: @MarkFrankli Try `var_dump( $split[1] );` and see if everything is what you expect.

Comment: Yes, actually I had a hidden `<br>` tag in it.

Comment: @MarkFrankli That explains the 4 extra characters. If my answer helped you out then feel free to accept it.